# date format in PHP date function

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

Hi I have values stored in MSSQL database as time(7)

job_start
job_end

I am trying to work out the difference between these two times using php, i have the folowing code

```
$start = $model->job_start; 
$end = $model->job_end;
$diff = date( "h:i:s", strtotime($end) - strtotime($start) ) ; 
echo $diff ;
```

However the output is

```
03:06:00
```

Rather than

```
00:06:00
```

By the way the difference is 6 minutes (360 seconds), can anyone help get this in the right format so i can save it ?

This question has been marked as a duplicate, however it is a different question as this addresses a specific timezone question when using the date function. And has been answered as such.

**EDIT**

The code i have marked answered the question i asked however I am trying to add an extra calculation as follows

```
$start = $model->job_start;
$end = $model->job_end;

$total = $model->customer->total_time;
//adding time difference to total time used for that customer
$dt =   strtotime($total) +  strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$hours = floor($dt / 3600);
$minutes = floor($dt / 60) - $hours * 60;
$seconds = $dt - $hours * 3600 - $minutes * 60;


// Padded values
$hours = str_pad($hours, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');
$minutes = str_pad($minutes, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');
$seconds = str_pad($seconds, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');
$output = "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}" ;

//display 
echo '<br> Start time : '. $start;
echo '<br> End time : '. $end;
echo '<br> total time + time difference : '. $output;
echo '<br> Total time for Customer : '. CHtml::encode($model->customer->total_time);
```

I am trying to add the difference between the total times to a total time variable 
However when output is echoed i get this display

```
Start time : 11:45:00.0000000
End time   : 12:45:00.0000000
total time + time difference : 382015:00:00
Total time for Customer : 09:00:00.0000000
```

Note that the total time + time difference has extra digits before it , its probably a simple mistake on my part but I can't see it , any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do `$end` and `$start` contain?

Comment: Show us some data sample, like $start and $end values

Comment: did you ask this same question yesterday? if so why are you asking it again ?

Comment: @sgroves Sorry for the confusion I just saw this as a separate question as I moved further with the solution and this is more PHP specific whereas the last was more yii, I have just updated my other question with this information, if this isn't the way things should be done let me know and I shall delete this one

Comment: my bad, i now see you edited that one to include the date diff question. best thing would probably be to remove your edits from the old question so this question stands on its own (i don't think anyone will notice/care if you don't though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `date` gives date since Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00) so the odd three hour difference you see there is your timezone. You need to parse the hours, minutes and seconds separately.

```
<?php
$end = '2013-07-30 23:27:00';
$start = '2013-07-30 21:23:56';

$dt = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$hours = floor($dt / 3600);
$minutes = floor($dt / 60) - $hours * 60;
$seconds = $dt - $hours * 3600 - $minutes * 60;

// Padded values
$hours = str_pad($hours, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');
$minutes = str_pad($minutes, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');
$seconds = str_pad($seconds, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT, '0');

$output = "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
```

Comment: if you're running 5.3 or later you could also try the date_diff function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php (haven't used this but it looks like it will do the job)

Comment: I am trying to perform an extra calculation with the code you have shown and it is showing extra numbers before the time string when echoing it, please see the edited question

Comment: If you wish to use date formatting to format the hours and smaller units (do not use this for days as compatibility breaks there) you can also use `gmdate('H:i:s', strtotime($end) - strtotime($start))` which removes timezone offsets.

Comment: Forget my previous comment. The issue is this: `strtotime` with hours only will use the current day. It is removed in `$start - $end`, but the current day you still have once in `strtotime($total)`. The whole time calculations should be rewritten now that I know the scope, but if you calculate total as `$total = strtotime($model->customer->total_time) - strtotime('00:00:00')` the current day will be removed.

Comment: I would break the times into pieces now that I know you are not working with full dates but only with hours. [Here is a gist for you](https://gist.github.com/adrenalin/6121332)

Comment: I can't thank you enough mate , that worked cheers. I had an issue where i had to remove the seconds in the code in the controller ( it gave an error about undefined offset 2 ), i just removed the '+ (float) $end[2], i don't need the seconds anyway , thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Why not do this in the database

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, job_start, job_end);
```

Its faster and it is clearer for others to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: If this returns a parsed string (seems to be preferred) this would definitely be the way to go. However here the issue in my opinion is just the use of `date` which returns the value with timezone.